# Docker - cant ping from mac to a machine from host - ping timeout

Tags: docker

I have the bellow configuration with netwok bridge under mac siera.
I inspect the ipaddress docker gave to my mahcine (172.20.0.5).
But, when i `ping 172.20.0.5`  i get timeout.
Also the gateway gets timeout `ping 172.20.0.5`

```
version: "3.5"

networks:
  main:
    driver: bridge
    name : main 

services:
  nginx_client: 
    networks: main
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  nginx_server: 
    networks: main
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

**UPDATE**

this is how i discovered the ip address

```
a-mac$ docker inspect docker_nginx_server_1 | grep 172
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.20.0.5",
```

Comment: Is your gateway in the same network as your host?

Comment: @bharath see my  my edit. seems to be the same

Comment: You're not able to ping but you're able to connect to the docker container? Is that right?

Comment: @bharath thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bridge network is used to isolate your container from your host network and that's why you're not able to ping from your host since your host and container is on different networks.

If you try the below command, you will find that it works:

```
docker run -it docker_nginx_server_1 ping 172.20.0.5
```

You can also try the following command to check if a specific port exposed on the container is working (Let's assume the port being 80):

```
telnet 172.20.0.5 80
```

For binding a port from your container to your host, you can do:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker_nginx_server_1
```

This will bind the port 80 of your container to port 80 of your host so that you can access the nginx server from your browser like:

```
http://localhost
```

For more information about networking in docker, you can refer to the following link:

https://docs.docker.com/network/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. So whats the alternative if not bridge? I want to access from my browser to nginx

Comment: Edited my answer. Check my answer now.

Comment: Thanks,I have 2+ nginx in the same environment. all of them needs to be on port 80 and a different IP address. I also need custom domain.

Comment: Then you can separate them with different nginx configs and different `server_name` directive on nginx config. This way when you create 2 different domains, let's say `example.com` and `example1.com` and point them both to same IP address, which is your docker host's IP address, the routing will happen based on the `server_name` directive in the config. So your nginx `server_name` directive should contain `example.com` and `example1.com` respectively on container nginx configs.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that i need to remove the network, in the /etc/hosts point them to the docker main address and it will work based on the 2 nginx vhost? if so, how can i know the main address?

Comment: The comment above might not explain clearly how to do it. So here's the simple answer: run 2 nginx conatiners and expose them under different ports other than 80 (let's say 8080 and 8081). Create a nginx config on your host listening on port 80 and do a reverse proxy based on `server_name` directive to port 8080 or 8081 respectively. Hope this explained clearly.

Comment: For information on how to do reverse proxy, you can refer to this link [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).

Comment: So i need 3 nginxs. 1 - domain1.com 2- domain2.com 3- proxy that will pass the reqests based on host and port?

Comment: Basically you'll create 2 vhosts on your host machine listening on port 80 and do reverse proxy to containers from those vhosts.

Comment: Yes 2 on containers(1 each on container) and 1 on your host which will do the proxy pass.

Comment: ohhh. i see.    thanks. how come there isnt simple networking solution for that inside docker?

Comment: Basically the routing for containers will be done by `docker swarm` or `kubernertes ingress`. But since you're not using any orchestration, you've to do it manually.